# Is it possible to manually invoke a zsh completion function?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

If I am at a zsh prompt and I have the current "context" (partially completed command-line command)

```
% man gr_
        ^ here I have used _ to  represent the cursor
```

If I then invoke the `_complete_help` function <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd></kbd><kbd>h</kbd>

It tells me the context is

```
% man gr_
tags in context :completion::complete:man::
    manuals  (_man)
```

If I am reading this output correctly - I can see there is a completer function `_man` that is capable of listing all the known man pages - which would be invoked if I hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key at this point.
My question is, can I call the `_man` completer function manually? rather than having `_man` being invoked by compsys (which itself is invoked by <kbd>Tab</kbd>)?

I have tried using the zle minibuffer `<Esc>x` , then type `_man<Enter>` but I think the mini-buffer is only capable of understanding zle commands, not executing general functions.

Answer (score 2):

I found that yes its possible and usable for simple completion functions, but because, this particular function `_man` does some parsing and validation work, it generates an error when invoked outside of its expected context.

Here's what I did to bind the `_man` completion function to a key combination so it could be invoked manually.

Define a wrapper function that sets the required options.

```
_man_autonomous () {
  eval $_comp_setup
  _man "$@"
}
```

Register a new widget with the line editor:

```
zle -C complete-man expand-or-complete _man_autonomous
```

bind the widget to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
bindkey '^T' complete-man
```

There is an [example of this technique using `_files` in the zsh FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq04.html#l52).

Comment: The problem was nonexistent manpath entries. Completion functions expect a set of options including `null_glob` and calling individual functions directly does not set those options. See my edit.

Comment: @Gilles thanks for that. After running the code you provided, I get no response (no errors either). i.e. after running your code in a zsh terminal, I then type: `% man gr<CTRL-T>` - gives no response. I also tried running in a zsh shell without sourcing my `~/.zshrc` and also using an ordinary widget instead of a completion widget i.e. I used `zle -N complete-man _man_autonomous`. this produced multiple errors e.g. `_man:3: bad math expression: operand expected at == ((  - 1...'`

Comment: Did you press Ctrl+T twice? By default `expand-or-complete` requires this on an ambiguous prefix. You might have Tab bound to a different widget if you don't usually do that (I have it bound to `complete-word`).

Comment: @Gilles pressing `CTRL-T` twice still causes no response. It would be nice if I could just bind to a normal widget, but from your code it seems that `_man_autonomous`  runs in its own context (own process or subshell) for purposes of constraining its scope (not polluting the main parent shell) - it needs  to do the setup produced by `eval $_comp_setup` AND then  `_man_autonomous` needs to be called with arguments which `_man "$@"` uses. obviously those arguments are normally provided by the completion system upon invocation.

Comment: You can't call a completion function outside of a completion context. I have no idea why this doesn't work for you, it works for me on zsh 5.0.7 both with my own configuration and with a `.zshrc` that contains only `autoload -U compinit; compinit` and the code in this answer. Try calling `set -x` and invoking the widget, and reading through the trace (but the trace may be very long, it can be difficult to locate the problem).

Comment: @Gilles ah you just gave me the clue I was missing. I needed to launch a "clean" zsh shell which didn't source my `~/.zshrc`. But per your comment I needed to add back `autoload -U compinit; compinit`. then I ran the code from this answer and it works. Obviously code from my `~/.zshrc` was the problem. If I had to guess, it might be the fact I run `setopt noautomenu` and `setopt nomenucomplete`. Either way it was something in `zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why zsh doesn't provide this functionality... Luckily someone made a hack: https://github.com/Valodim/zsh-capture-completion

```
$ capture.zsh 'man gr'
grep
<snip>
groff
<snip>
```